# Wifi hotspot generates new mac address each time

Tags: wifi-hotspot, mac-address

Every time I'm gonna to use wifi hotspot on my device it generates new mac address, therefore my laptop can't remember for permanent. Every time I need to set all connections details  again anad again. It's a bit annoying.

Is there a way to make android generate the same mac address each time?

ps. currently I'm using android 4.2.2 ( cm 10.1-20130521 ), unfortunately such behaviour was long before current version.